# TLS client server's certificate chain verification without servername verification

Tags: go, ssl, tls1.2

Is it possible to do server's certificate chain verification without verifying servername in Go TLS client from `crypto/tls` package?

As shown in the below code snippet, if we don't provide any servername we get error like

> tls: either ServerName or InsecureSkipVerify must be specified in the
>   tls.Config

```golang
rootCA := x509.NewCertPool()
caCert, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("/path/to/ca_cert.pem")
rootCA.AppendCertsFromPEM(caCert)

tlsConfig = tls.Config{
    RootCAs:    rootCA,
    ServerName: "xyz.com",
}

conn, _ := net.Dial("tcp", "ip:port")

c := tls.Client(conn, &tlsConfig)
c.Handshake()
```

I have a requirement where only server's certificate chain verification is required and servername verification not needed but with Go's `crypto/tls` package both verification is coupled as an unit.

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/#Config.VerifyPeerCertificate

Comment: *"...I have a requirement where only server's certificate chain verification is required and servername verification not needed ..."* - please question this requirement since it likely leads to insecure behavior: any certificate issued by a trusted CA can be used to MITM connections to arbitrary destinations. If this requirement is only because the name in the certificate does not match the name you connect to then you might provide the expected name in `tlsConfig.ServerName` instead.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, the intent here is clearly to check for a valid chain rooted at a specific CA, not to accept any valid chain (which would be equivalent to InsecureSkipVerify). If the root CA is controlled and properly protected by the OP I see no issue, although I agree that it's unusual to not know the server name.